# Question on existence of almost length-minimizing curve in a general domain?

Tags: gn.general-topology, curves

I have the following question: for a general domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that for each pair of points $x,y\in \Omega$, there exists a curve $\gamma$ connecting $x$ and $y$ in $\Omega$, almost length minimizing in the sense that, for each pair $z,w\in \gamma$, the length of $\gamma_{zw}$ satisfies
$$\text{length}(\gamma_{zw})\leq 2\inf_{\beta \text{ connects }z, w \text{ in } \Omega}\text{length}(\beta).$$
Here $\gamma_{zw}$ denotes the restriction of $\gamma$ from $z$ to $w$.

Thanks for any comments and suggestions.

---

Edit: the topic is closed.

Here one needs piecewise linear approximation of a general curve.

Comment: Are you requiring $\gamma$ to be simple?  If not, then what does $\gamma_{z w}$ mean?

Comment: Yes, you can fix a $\gamma$ that almost minimizes the total length, and then approximate by straight line segments in small balls (cover $\gamma$ by finitely many of these).

Comment: Please delete the question; here it's just self-vandalized. I rolled back to original question and added your sentence.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question. The formulation needs to be slightly improved BUT the answer is not trivial as what the comments suggest. I will post a proof sooner or later.